# How to create a function to display an alert message after deleting data

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I am getting started with Vue 3. I am struggling to create a function to display an alert message after deleting some data.

My delete function looks like this:

```
const deleteProduct = (arg) => {
  router.delete(`/api/product/${arg}`)
  showMsg()
}
```

I am trying to create a function to display an alert message after deleting some data passing the delete function on the button as below:

```
<button class="flex items-center text-danger" v-on:click="deleteProduct(product.id)"
     data-tw-toggle="modal" data-tw-target="#delete-confirmation-modal">
     <Trash2 class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" /> Deletar
</button>
```

I believe I need to use something like the below to create a function to display an alert message after deleting, however I cannot figure out how to do this!

```
function showMsg() {
  if (deleteProdut() === -1) {
    const msgDelete = ref('Produto deletado com sucesso!')

    setTimeout(() => msg.value = "", 3000)
  }
}
```

Comment: refs should be declared at the top-level scope of your component (just inside `<script setup>` or `setup()` function if you're using that),  see [declaring reactive state](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state).  You haven't shown where/how your delete message is being displayed, but your `showMsg` function assigns `msgDelete` but after the timeout clears out `msg`, which are obviously two different variables, why is that?  The if statement `deleteProdut() === -1` also has no context so I'm not sure how or when that's ever true.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```js
<template>
    <button class="flex items-center text-danger" @click="deleteProduct(product.id)"">
     <Trash2 class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" /> Delete
    </button>
</template>

<script setup>
function deleteProduct(productId) {
    // Logic to delete the product
    // After the deletion is completed, trigger the alert
    showAlert('Product deleted')
}

function showAlert(message) {
    // Login to show the alert with the message you receive here
}
</script>
```

The logic to show the modal/message/toast, should be managed inside the delete action. Those tags on the `button` element are not necessary.

We don't have so much context about how your code is working, but I did my best based on what I can appreciate here.